# Procedures query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
JOIN (select distinct to_number(unnest(string_to_array(p_cmsid, ',')))) x(SUPPLIER_CMSID)
                 USING (SUPPLIER_CMSID)
                  JOIN (select distinct unnest(string_to_array(p_service_name, ','))) y(NET_SERVICE_NAME)
                 USING (NET_SERVICE_NAME)
```

Any one please explain this query

Comment: That is not valid SQL in any dialect of which I'm aware (in fact, it isn't even **close** to valid). What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like some sort of proprietary Application Scripting language. Please check the manual of the application this language belong to

Comment: that query was used in postgresql procedure

Comment: No. No it wasn't. That is not valid PostgreSQL.

Comment: If asking questions like this please provide the inputs and results, relevant database table structures, etc. This isn't even a whole query.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, the snippet shows 2 JOINS in a larger FROM clause.

```
FROM DATA D
JOIN (<subquery>) x(SUPPLIER_CMSID)
     USING (SUPPLIER_CMSID)
JOIN (<subquery>) y(NET_SERVICE_NAME)
     USING (NET_SERVICE_NAME)
```

Things to note here:

1. USING is a JOIN syntax to implicitly join by the same-named column on both sides, e.g. the first one translates to
     `ON D.SUPPLIER_CMSID = x.SUPPLIER_CMSID`
2. PostgreSQL and SQL Server allow you to name the columns in a derived table at the same time as aliasing it. `x(SUPPLIER_CMSID)` aliases the derived table as `x` while at the same time aliasing the single column in it as `SUPPLIER_CMSID`.

The other parts:

1. [unnest/string_to_array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html) are string to array and array to row operators. Combined, it can turn a delimited string into a multi-row resultset
2. to_number - converts a string to number. When used with unnest, it converts each row's singular column from string to number. Your code snippet however is missing the format (2nd argument)

If the entire portion of code works (unsure about `to_number()` in that context), then the JOINs would serve as a filters by taking in two strings `p_cmsid` and `p_servicename` and is roughly equivalent to

```
FROM DATA D
WHERE SUPPLIER_CMSID = {list in p_cms_id}
  AND NET_SERVICE_NAME = {list in p_servicename}
```

### EXAMPLE

Here's an example that shows `to_number(text,text)`, `unnest(array)` and `string_to_array(string, delimiter)` working together: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/620/0)

```
select *
  from (select to_number(
               unnest(
               string_to_array('123,433,434',',')),'999')) tbl(col);
```